# Reading perl flat file db with php

Tags: php, perl, flat-file, dbm, gdbm

I have an old flat file perl db that's part of an eCommerce site I want to migrate to a new php application.

Is it possible to read with php the "table" files have no file extension and seem not be just csv's or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have the kind of Perl database that's accessed with a so-called bound hash.

This uses technology generically known as `dbm`.  The most recent implementation is `gdbm`, a GNU version, that's described here. http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/  It's likely (but not 100% certain) that's the version used by the Perl infrastructure of your old app.

There's a PHP API with functions like `dba_open()` that also supports `dbm` variants. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dba.php .  You should be able to handle that file of yours with it.

It's worth observing that this `dba_` extension wasn't loaded in my php implementation until I enabled it explicitly. You may have to mess around with various `dbm` implementations until you find the one that matches. The three I know about are the original UNIX one, `dbm`, `ndbm`, and `gdbm`.